# What questions do I need to ask for a database syncing without testing?

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

I am currently helping to implement an RFID inventory management system for my company.  The software that we are locked into has been at best buggy and unreliable.  The software provider is now rolling out a major release.

My problem is that the new software release keeps a local database on each machine that then syncs to a master database online.  According to the software company we cannot do a scaled rollout because of data corruption issues between the software releases.  What questions can I be asking and what sort of testing can I do on my end to make sure this software works?  Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should set up a clone of your production server, with several clients. 
Have the vendor upgrade this clone, and then setup as many client-machines as you can spare to use the cloned system.

Test this cloned setup in isolation, and as much as possible close to real-world usage (several people performing operations at once, etc). 
If any bugs are identified, and the vendor wants to deliver a new version you should ideally roll back the cloned environment back to when you took the snapshot, and have them perform the upgrade scenario again.

It may be possible to automate the stress testing of the setup.